# rolling joins with duplicate keys

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)


masterdf <- data.table(time = c(ymd('2019-02-01'),
                                ymd('2019-02-01'),
                                ymd('2019-03-01')),
                       var = c(1,2,3))

masterdf[, mykey := time]
setkey(masterdf, 'mykey')
> masterdf
         time var      mykey
1: 2019-02-01   1 2019-02-01
2: 2019-02-01   2 2019-02-01
3: 2019-03-01   3 2019-03-01
```

and

```
slavedf <- data.table(timeref = c(ymd('2019-01-01'),
                                  ymd('2019-01-28'),
                                  ymd('2019-01-29')))

slavedf[, mykey := timeref]
setkey(slavedf, 'mykey')
> slavedf
      timeref      mykey
1: 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
2: 2019-01-28 2019-01-28
3: 2019-01-29 2019-01-29
```

What I am trying to achieve is a classic rolling join problem. For each date in `masterdf`, what is the closest previous date in `slavedf`?

Using the following syntax returns puzzling results:

```
> #rolling join
> masterdf[slavedf, roll = - Inf]
         time var      mykey    timeref
1: 2019-02-01   1 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
2: 2019-02-01   1 2019-01-28 2019-01-28
3: 2019-02-01   1 2019-01-29 2019-01-29
```

As you can see, one would expect the two `2019-02-01` dates from `masterdf` to be matched with the same (closest) `2019-01-29` date from `slavedf`, and `2019-03-01` from `masterdf` to be matched with `2019-01-29` as well.

Here you can see this is not the case and that `2019-03-01` is not even present in the output... I think comes from the duplicate keys. Any idea what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd try `slavedf[masterdf, roll = T]`. It gives `Jan-29` though as this is the closest one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
slavedf[masterdf, roll = T]
```

This gives:

```
      timeref      mykey       time var
1: 2019-01-29 2019-02-01 2019-02-01   1
2: 2019-01-29 2019-02-01 2019-02-01   2
3: 2019-01-29 2019-03-01 2019-03-01   3
```

Let's take for our main data frame `df` (`X`) and the secondary data frame `df1` (`Y`).

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 B = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3)
)

df1 <- data.frame(A = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  val = c(1000, 100, 500)
)
```

Left join with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% left_join(df1, by = "A")

  A B  val
1 A 2 1000
2 A 2 1000
3 A 3 1000
4 B 4  100
5 B 3  100
```

What is then the left join in `data.table`? Perhaps:

```
setDT(df)
setDT(df1)

df[df1, on = "A"]

   A  B  val
1: A  2 1000
2: A  2 1000
3: A  3 1000
4: B  4  100
5: B  3  100
6: C NA  500
```

Perhaps not - what about:

```
setDT(df)
setDT(df1)

df1[df, on = "A"]

   A  val B
1: A 1000 2
2: A 1000 2
3: A 1000 3
4: B  100 4
5: B  100 3
```

Yep! This is also explained in [this vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) as `X[DT, on="x"]                         # left join`.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work indeed. could you please explain why this work? what is the logic here?

Comment: It's the standard way of translating 'what is there in data frame B (`slavedf`) that comes just before data frame A (`masterdf`)'. Your way of putting it is used for checking what comes just after - and as such it produced the right results.

Comment: what is puzzling is that for me the syntax `X[Y]` means X left join Y. Am I right? Essentially I am trying to do a left join (keeping all rows in X) while rolling the key in Y (find the closest key in Y to the current key in X)

Comment: If I understood correctly what you mean by `X` and `Y`, actually in `data.table` `X left join Y` would be `Y[X]`. So the other way around compared to some other frameworks/packages (e.g. `X %>% left_join(Y)`).

Comment: man this is so confusing... are you sure? I m pretty sure I ve seen the contrary in the docs...

Comment: See my demo in my post here

Comment: thanks! that is just insane to use just the opposite of the convention every other language in the world uses.... :) just one follow up: why using `roll = TRUE` instead of `roll = -Inf` then?

Comment: `roll = TRUE` gives first value equal or lower, and `roll = -Inf` first value equal or higher :)

Comment: do you know what is the purpose of `rollends` in this context?